# Ошибка перехода по ссылкам второго уровня при использовании html5 history api

Tags: ajax, html5-history-api, history-api

Использую history.js (html5 history api). При переходе по ссылкам которые находятся на том же уровне все хорошо, т.е. `index.html`, `one.html`, `two.html`. Если же пытаюсь перейти по ссылке на втором уровне, например, `papka/three.html`, то переход идет почему-то на `papka/papka/three.html`. А такого файла соответственно нет. В чем может быть ошибка?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var location = window.history.location || window.location;
    $(document).on('click', 'a.link', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        history.pushState(null, null, $(this).attr('href'));

        var link = $(this).attr('href');
        if (link == 'index.html') {
            $('#content').prev('.slider').show();
        } else {
            $.ajax({
                type:'post',
                url: link,
                success: function(mes){
                    $('#content').prev('.slider').hide();
                    $('#content').html(mes);
                    $(window).scroll();
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Из этого примера не понятно, при чем тут вообще History API / History.js. Если убрать строчку history.pushState(null, null, $(this).attr('href')); то как ваша навигация вообще изменится? Вы кликаете по линку, берете href, дальше делаете POST-запрос. При чем тут history-то?

Comment: если не использовать history.pushState(null, null, $(this).attr('href')); то url не меняется, но все переходы отрабатывают на отлично

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лучше использовать абсолютные ссылки.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась просто. Ссылки по которым осуществлялся переход были вида - papka/three.html изменил на ../papka/three.html. Все стало отлично.